# swagger-ui: How to add a header-param request to every-api

Tags: swagger-ui, quarkus

I am new to quarkus and have a bit familiar with swagger-ui. I am able to add a @Parameter to the an endpoint like this:

```
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER, required = true, name = "my-header-id")
```

But, I would like to add this param to every endpoint. How can I achieve this?

I am using `quarkus-smallrye-openapi` for the ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify parameters on method or class level. If you define the param as class field, then it will be added to all methods of the corresponding endpoint:

```
@Path("/someendpoint")
public class MyEndpoint {
  
    @HeaderParam("my-header-id")
    @Parameter(name = "my-header-id")
    String myHeaderId;

    @GET
    public Response getAll() {return Response.ok().build()}

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Response someMethod(@PathParam("id") String id) {return Response.ok().build();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! I was also wondering how can I add the `@Parameter()` to every endpoint in application and not only a particular controller.

Comment: I do not thing that is possible with annotations+runtime generator. If it is that important, then you could instead of runtime schema generator switch to maven plugin(not sure if there is one for MP annotations but you could easily tweak Swagger maven plugin, or openapi maven plugin) and have some kind of config with which you'd add the params to all generated methods. Not sure if that is worth the effort though

Comment: It is possible by adding the header param in a `BaseController` and extending all other controller with the `BaseController`